# Antcontrib <for> and <var unset="true"> in ant?

Tags: for-loop, unset, ant-contrib

What versions of Antcontrib support <for> and also <var unset="true" /> in Antcontrib?

(Or where can I go to find out that information?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The task docs are [here](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html), but they don't say which versions of the library support which functions. However, there haven't been any new releases for years, so I suspect you already have the latest.

Note that there is no `<var unset="true"/>`, it's `<Variable unset="true"/>`. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @skaffman All the documentation for the Variable says var in all the examples: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html

Comment: @skaffman What about for did they change that to something else?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.0b2 has the for task, but you have to go in and uncomment it from the antcontrib.properties file in the jar.  version 1.0b3 removes that task (from what I can tell).  Not sure about unset, but 1.0b2 has the var task.

Hope that answers your question.