# The <var> type doesn't support the "unset" attribute

Tags: linux, ant, ant-contrib

I read a doc of [Ant-Contrib Index](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html). It is saying that we should to use `<var>` tag only with the unset property.

right now i am using /ant/1.6.2 version of ant.

I went through [Antcontrib <for> and <var unset="true"> in ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307132/antcontrib-for-and-var-unset-true-in-ant)
but did not get my answer.

We are using `ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar` for this

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If you are a beginner in ANT avoid use of the ant-contrib extension. It's not part of core ANT.

Comment: I am getting The <var> type doesn't support the “unset” attribute problem in our legacy code. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks!!! I am just using old written code. Could you please give a thought to it. Why it came?